# Can't send POST request from React front-end to Node.js back-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a simple node.js portfolio page built with which includes a contact page that I use a third-party API to send emails with (sendgrid). The information for the sendgrid API query is saved to `sendgridObj`and I make a POST request with it to my server at `server.js` upon submitting the contact form.

```
//CONTACT.JS PAGE

emailApi = () => {
let sendgridObj = {
  to: 'caseyclinga@gmail.com',
  from: this.state.from,
  subject: this.state.subject,
  text: this.state.text
  }
this.resetState();
axios.post('/contact', sendgridObj)
  .then(res => console.log(`CONTACT.JS RESPONSE: ${res}`)) 
  .catch(err => console.log(`CONTACT.JS ERROR: ${err}`)); 
}
```

On the backend, I set up my route for `/contact` and make a POST request with the `sendgridObj` to sendgrid mail.

```
//SERVER.JS FILE

const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const SgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
const path = require('path');

SgMail.setApiKey(process.env.REACT_APP_SENDGRID_API_KEY);

//Middleware stuff

app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body) 
  SgMail.send(req.body)
  .then(res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)))
  .catch(err => console.log(`SERVER.JS ERROR: ${err}`));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
```

All relatively straight forward stuff. This was all working well until a few days ago when it inexplicably stopped funcitoning. When I run `console.log(req.body)` on my back-end, it shows the object I sent so it's not an issue with the `req.body`. It's also not an issue with my API key and I receive a 202 in the response object from Sendgrid (catches no errors).

However, about 45 seconds or so after submitting the contact form, the front end catches a 500 error  `POST http://localhost:3000/contact 500 (Internal Server Error)`. 
Then I noticed if I reset my server, I get a proxy error on my backend `Proxy error: Could not proxy request /contact from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.`

So it seems like I have an issue with my routes or somehow with sending the request to Sendgrid but I'm completely confused as to why. I can console log the query object to show it's being sent to the backend and then I get a 202 response but still I am getting an error? If it could not proxy my request, then why was the object still sent?

Here is my whole code: https://github.com/caseycling/portfolio

Comment: are you using a database or all-request middleware?

Answer (score 0):

You should create baseURL for both on backend and frontend. Example:

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

Then, you should use the created instance to get or post for integrating with backend.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like your react server and your node js server is running in different port.

2 thing you need to handle is:

- Specify full baseURL to node js backend
- Add [cors](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) config for node js and run

  npm install cors

Then add this in your node.js code

```
var cors = require('cors')

var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

Comment: I actually had that already in my server.js file but it hasn't done anything. I think what is happening is google is blocking my server from sending files to gmail since I sent so many in such a short time during development.